# Gradio: How to retrieve uploaded file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, gradio

when I upload a file using the upload_button in Gradio, the file is stored in a Temp file in a known location but the file name changes because there is a random suffix addition when it is saved.

ie.:

- uploaded original file name: `what_is_langchain_test.txt`
- new file name: `AppData\Local\Temp\what_is_langchain_test2hyhuc5m`

How can I retrieve the file for further processing?

Thanks.